# Select Element doesn't work after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, twitter-bootstrap

**Hi! Guys I know nothing when it comes to JQuery... Please help me with this.**

I created bootstrap form with a button add another field if the user want additional input fields. The new field are cloned from the original field.

The date-picker didn't work at first (on cloned field) so I add code to solve that.. (which I was luck to do and it took me 7hrs to get it correct)..

but then I found out even the cloned select box aren't working also. 
-> Since the selector was using ID (#e1), I thought that was a reason so I changed it to class (.e1). That didn't help.
->So I tried the same method (like how I did on date-picker) but it also failed..

Here is the Code:
-> At Page header

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function cloneRow()
    {

        var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1); 
        var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to

        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
        clone.id = "row" + num; // change id or other attributes/contents
        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
        clone.querySelectorAll('[id="id-date-picker-1"]')[0].id = "id-date-picker-" + num;  //Put Unique ID   

    //For Selector
    $(function(){

        $('.e1').select2();

        $('.clone').click(function() {

            var clone = $('.select2').clone();

            var cloned = clone.find('.e1');
            cloned.removeClass('select2').removeAttr('id');

            clone.appendTo('.elements');
            $(cloned).select2();

        });
    });


    }
</script>
```

The Row to be cloned

```
<tbody id="rowToClone">
<tr>
    <td>

        <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
    <select class="e1" style="width:100%;">
        <option value="AL" />Alabama
        <option value="AK" />Alaska
        <option value="AZ" />Arizona
    </select>

        </div>

    </td>

    <td>

        <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
    <select class="e1" style="width:100%;">
        <option value="VA" />Virginia
        <option value="WA" />Washington

    </select>
        </div>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

-> The trigger button

```
<button type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" class="btn btn-default purple"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add </button>
```

->Page Footer

```
//On Page Footer

    //--Jquery Select2--
    $(".e1").select2(); //I added this line
    $("#e1").select2();
    $("#e2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true
    });
```

-> Please help me.. I will appreciate.

Comment: Lot of code chopping there! Hard to understand the flow.

Comment: Okay let me try to edit it and leave the HTML and Js

Comment: A lot of plugins, that change the DOM, simply do not like to be cloned. In the past I have had to un-datepicker the elements on a shallow clone and apply a dataPicker to it fresh.

Comment: I think is the same way to archive my goal, by destroy the select Event on clone and rebuild it again... but I don't know that code... JQuery is new to me.

Comment: Answer added. Note your `option` html was invalid, which caused blank `selects` in your example so I also fixed that. You will note that this method reduces the whole problem to a couple of, much simpler, lines of code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems (your HTML for the options is invalid), but a lot of plugins, that change the DOM, simply do not like to be cloned. They store instance information in element `data` and are often not re-entrant (cannot reapply the plugin to elements that already have the DOM changes).

As taking existing rows to clone can get messy, I would suggest a slightly different approach to the cloning, that will avoid these problems.

Simply keep a separate template row in your page, that you can clone, inside a dummy script block:

```
<script id="rowToClone" type="text/template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                <select class="e1" style="width:100%;">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option></select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                <select class="e1" style="width:100%;">
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option></select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                <input type="text" class="datapicker"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

`type="text/template"` is unknown, so the `script` is ignored by all browsers.

Then the clone becomes as simple as:

```
$('#clonerow').click(function(){
    $('#table tbody').append($('#rowToClone').html());
    // now apply any plugins to the new row
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j1smswmt/2/

Here is an expanded version with `datepicker` applied to each new row:

```
$('#clonerow').click(function(){
    $('#table tbody').append($('#rowToClone').html()).find('tr:last .datapicker').datepicker();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j1smswmt/3/

**Notes:**

- Your options are currently invalid. You need to enclose the text inside matching `<option>` & `</option>` tags.
- As you are using jQuery avoid using inline `onclick` handlers. They separate the event registration from the event handler for no real benefit. Do it the jQuery way instead.

Comment: Thank's the code helped the select element to be visible and clicked, how ever, they do not support the search and Date-picker.. But let me continue to try I will send a link to the page and code if I failed   @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still experience this issue but would still want to use the jQuery clone:

If you are using Bootstrap, you actually just need to remove the bootstrap-select and then reinitialise the normal cloned select.

Just add these two lines of code after you do your clone:

```
clone.find('.bootstrap-select').remove();
clone.find('select').selectpicker();
```

Based on answer from this Github issue: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/605